# Javascript: Reassigned variable being mutated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any idea why my variable assignment is being mutated? This seems like something simple but I'm just not sure what's going on.

Below, an object of data is passed into the `pullChecklist` function as a prop. I want to take this data, create a copy (`newPage`), change the ids in that copy and then save the copy in state.

However, whenever I try and change the ids in the copy `newPage`, the ids also change in `page`. This is confirmed by the 3 console logs.

If I remove the if statement all together and just leave the `Original Assignment` and `Original Assignment 2` console logs, the data is exactly as when it is sent as a prop. Adding the if statement mutates all the console logs to the version with updated ids.

```
const pullChecklist = (page) => {
    console.log('Original Assignment', page.components[0].blocks)
    let newPage = page
    if (newPage.components[0].blocks) {

      newPage.components[0].blocks.map((block) => {
        if (block.type === 'checklist') {
        
          let newTest = uuidv4()
          block.id = newTest

          for (const c in block.data) {
            let newId = uuidv4()
            block.data[c].id = newId
          }
          console.log('Reformatted', block);
        }
      });
    }
    console.log('Original Assignment 2', page.components[0].blocks);

  };
```

Why is the data from `page` being mutated? Thank you!

EDIT:

As pointed out by @Vlaz below, `let newPage = page` does not copy the object.

I used: `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));` in order to properly copy the object.

Comment: `let newPage = page` does not make a copy of the object. It just makes another reference to it.

Comment: @VLAZ How would I create a new copy of the object?

Comment: For clone obj you can do for exemple : const newPage = Object.assign({}, page) or 
const newPage = {...page}

Comment: @CyrilWallis-Davy both of these do only a shallow clone of the object.

Comment: I ended up going with obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));. I know it's less efficient but it works for my requirements. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: sorry you were talking about object copy, "not deep clone"